# dplyr summarise_each with na.rm

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to instruct `dplyr` to use `summarise_each` with `na.rm=TRUE`? I would like to take the mean of variables with `summarise_each("mean")` but I don't know how to specify it to ignore missing values.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Following the links in the doc, it seems you can use `funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))`:

```
library(dplyr)
by_species <- iris %>% group_by(Species)
by_species %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: After some years a comment to that: `summarise_each()`  is deprecated . 
In `summarise_all`, you can add `na.rm = TRUE` after the `funs` argument -

That is useful when you want to call more than one function such as:

`iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean, max, sd), na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 33):

**update**

the current dplyr version strongly suggests the use of `across` instead of the more specified functions `summarise_all` etc.

Translating the below syntax (naming the functions in a named list) into `across` could look like this:

```
library(dplyr)
ggplot2::msleep %>% 
  select(vore, sleep_total, sleep_rem) %>%
  group_by(vore) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), .f = list(mean = mean, max = max, sd = sd), na.rm = TRUE))

#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#>   vore  sleep_total_mean sleep_total_max sleep_total_sd sleep_rem_mean
#>   <chr>            <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 carni            10.4             19.4           4.67           2.29
#> 2 herbi             9.51            16.6           4.88           1.37
#> 3 inse~            14.9             19.9           5.92           3.52
#> 4 omni             10.9             18             2.95           1.96
#> 5 <NA>             10.2             13.7           3.00           1.88
#> # ... with 2 more variables: sleep_rem_max <dbl>, sleep_rem_sd <dbl>
```

---

**older answer**

`summarise_each` is deprecated now, here an option with `summarise_all`.

- One can still specify `na.rm = TRUE` *within* the `funs` argument (cf @flodel 's answer: just replace `summarise_each`  with `summarise_all` ).
- But you can also add `na.rm = TRUE` *after* the `funs` argument.

That is useful when you want to call more than only one function, e.g.:

**edit**

the `funs()` argument is now (soft)deprecated, thanks to comment @Mikko. One can use the suggestions that are given by the warning, see below in the code. `na.rm` can still be specified as additional argument within `summarise_all`.

I used `ggplot2::msleep` because it contains NAs and shows this better.

```r
library(dplyr)

ggplot2::msleep %>% 
  select(vore, sleep_total, sleep_rem) %>%
  group_by(vore) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean, max, sd), na.rm = TRUE)
#> Warning: funs() is soft deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0
#> Please use a list of either functions or lambdas: 
#> 
#>   # Simple named list: 
#>   list(mean = mean, median = median)
#> 
#>   # Auto named with `tibble::lst()`: 
#>   tibble::lst(mean, median)
#> 
#>   # Using lambdas
#>   list(~ mean(., trim = .2), ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Also `funs` is deprecated. The current command is `list(...)`

Comment: Just for completeness, e.g. using list(...)
 `summarise_all(list(
    minimum = ~ min(., na.rm = TRUE),
    maximum = ~ max(., na.rm = TRUE),
    s_dev = ~ sd(., na.rm = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 2):

Take for instance `mtcars` data set

```
library(dplyr)
```

You can always use `summarise` to avoid long syntax:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg, na.rm=T),
            sd_mpg = sd(mpg, na.rm = T))
```

Answer (score 2):

`summarise_at` function in `dplyr` will summarise a dataset at specific column and allow to remove NAs for each functions applied. Take iris dataset and compute mean and median for variables from Sepal.Length to Petal.Width.

```
library(dplyr)
summarise_at(iris,vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width),funs(mean,median),na.rm=T)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my answer will add something to the previous comments. Hopefully yes.

In my case, I had a database from an experiment with two groups (control, exp) with different levels for a specific variable (day) and I wanted to get a summary of mean and sd of another variable (weight) for each group for specific levels of the variable day.

Here is an example of my database:

> ```
> animal    group           day       weight      
> 1.1       "control"       73        NA   
> 1.2       "control"       73        NA   
> 3.1       "control"       73        NA   
> 9.2       "control"       73        25.2  
> 9.3       "control"       73        23.4  
> 9.4       "control"       73        25.8   
> 2.1       "exp"           73        NA       
> 2.2       "exp"           73        NA     
> 10.1      "exp"           73        24.4     
> 10.2      "exp"           73        NA     
> 10.3      "exp"           73        24.6
> ```

So, for instance, in this case I wanted to get the mean and sd of the weight on day 73 for each of the groups (control, exp), omitting the NAs.

I did this with this command:

```
data[data$day=="73",] %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(mean(weight[group == "exp"], na.rm=T),sd(weight[group == "exp"], na.rm=T))
data[data$day=="73",] %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(mean(weight[group == "control"], na.rm=T),sd(weight[group == "control"], na.rm=T))
```