# How to correctly use dplyr verbs inside a function definition in r?

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I want to use `filter` and `summarise` from `dplyr`  inside my function. Without a function it works like following:

```
library(dplyr)
> Orange %>% 
+     filter(Tree==1) %>% 
+     summarise(age_max = max(age))
  age_max
1    1582
```

I want to do the same inside a function, but following fails:

```
## Function definition:

df.maker <- function(df, plant, Age){

  require(dplyr)

  dfo <- df %>% 
    filter(plant==1) %>% 
    summarise(age_max = max(Age))

  return(dfo)
}

## Use:
> df.maker(Orange, Tree, age)

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in as.lazy_dots(list(...)) : object 'Tree' not found
```

I know that similar questions have been asked before. I've also gone through some relevant links such as [page1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) and [page2](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-mutate-from-dplyr-inside-a-function-getting-around-non-standard-evaluation/). But I can't fully grasp the concepts of NSE and SE. I tried following:

```
df.maker <- function(df, plant, Age){

  require(dplyr)

  dfo <- df %>% 
    filter_(plant==1) %>% 
    summarise_(age_max = ~max(Age))

  return(dfo)
}
```

But get the same error. Please help me understand what's going on. And how can I correctly create my function? Thanks!

EDIT:
I also tried following:

```
df.maker <- function(df, plant, Age){

  require(dplyr)

  dfo <- df %>% 
    #filter_(plant==1) %>% 
    summarise_(age_max = lazyeval::interp(~max(x),
                                          x = as.name(Age)))

  return(dfo)
}  

> df.maker(Orange, Tree, age)
 Error in as.name(Age) : object 'age' not found
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40017629/using-dplyr-within-a-function-non-standard-evaluation/40018601#40018601) answer your question?

Comment: @Axeman, I tried that, as shown in my edit. But it still doesn't work. I think it has something to do with environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either supply character arguments and use `as.name`:

```
df.maker1 <- function(d, plant, Age){
  require(dplyr)
  dfo <- d %>% 
    filter_(lazyeval::interp(~x == 1, x = as.name(plant))) %>% 
    summarise_(age_max = lazyeval::interp(~max(x), x = as.name(Age)))
  return(dfo)
}  
df.maker1(Orange, 'Tree', 'age')
```

> ```
>   age_max
> 1    1582
> ```

Or capture the arguments with `substitute`:

```
df.maker2 <- function(d, plant, Age){
  require(dplyr)
  plant <- substitute(plant)
  Age <- substitute(Age)

  dfo <- d %>% 
    filter_(lazyeval::interp(~x == 1, x = plant)) %>% 
    summarise_(age_max = lazyeval::interp(~max(x), x = Age))
  return(dfo)
}  
df.maker2(Orange, Tree, age)
```

> ```
>   age_max
> 1    1582
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about `substitute()`.